# Regular expression with a limited length, spaces and other limitations

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for the following regex:

- The match can be empty.
- If it is not empty, it must contain at least 2 characters which are English letters or digits.
- The regex must allow spaces between words.

This is what I come up with:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}$
```

It works fine, but it does not except spaces between words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you can use this regex to make sure we match all kind of spaces (even a hard space), and make sure we allow an empty string match:

```
(?i)^(?:[a-z0-9]{2}[a-z0-9\p{Zs}]*|)$
```

C#:

```
var rg11x = new Regex(@"(?i)^(?:[a-z0-9]{2}[a-z0-9\p{Zs}]*|)$");
var tst = rg11x.IsMatch("");                // true
var tst1 = rg11x.Match("Mc Donalds").Value; // Mc Donalds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^[a-zA-Z\d]{2}[a-zA-Z\d\s]*?$`

Here is also an useful site for learning and testing regex patterns.
http://regex101.com/